# Conditional if/then/else for JMESPath?

Tags: jq, jmespath

Am trying to do a simple if/then/else using JMESPath

For example: 'if the input is a string, return the string, else return the "value" property of the input'. An input of `"abc"` would return `"abc"`. An input of `{"value":"def"}` would return `"def"`

With `jq` this is easy: `if .|type == "string" then . else .value end`

With JMESPath, I can get the type

`type(@)`

or the input:

`@`

or the `value` property:

`value`

but I have not found a way to combine them into an if-then-else. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

**people[?general.id !=`100`] || people**

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "general": {
        "id": 100,
        "age": 20,
        "other": "foo",
        "name": "Bob"
      },
      "history": {
        "first_login": "2014-01-01",
        "last_login": "2014-01-02"
      }
    },
    {
      "general": {
        "id": 101,
        "age": 30,
        "other": "bar",
        "name": "Bill"
      },
      "history": {
        "first_login": "2014-05-01",
        "last_login": "2014-05-02"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

if else condition works here

Comment: This may not have answered the question (it had a downvote) but it actually answered my related question which got me here. || is great, so I could print one of two fields of an AWS CLI query based on the first one being null or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but not cleanly. The general form is to:

1. Make the value you are testing an array (wrap in square braces)
2. Apply the map function to map the filtered array to what value you want if true
3. At this point you have an array that is populated with one (true) item if the array filter passed, otherwise it is empty
4. Concat to that array one item (the false value)
5. Finally, take item at index 0 in this array - which will be the result of the condition

This should allow you to also derive possible transformations for both the false and true conditions

For example, if the test data is as so:

```
{
   "test": 11
}
```

Depending on the value you can get either produce the results (using test data 11 and 2 as example):

- "Yes, the value is 11 which is greater than 10"
- **OR**
- "No the value is 2 which is less than or equal to 10"

Like so:

```
[
    map(
        &join(' ', ['Yes, the value is', to_string(@), 'which is greater than 10']), 
        [test][? @ > `10`]
    ), 
    join(' ', ['No the value is', to_string(test), ' which is less than or equal to 10'])
][] | @[0]
```

So to abstract a template:

```
[
    map(
        &<True Expression Here>, 
        [<Expression you are testing>][? @ <Test Expression>]
    ), 
    <False Expression Here>)
][] | @[0]
```